# Which is the appropriate lifecycle hook to draw a line?

Tags: chart.js

I want to draw a line to show the zero value on a y axis. I have this working:

```
afterDraw(chart) {
      const {ctx, scales} = chart;

      Object.keys(scales).forEach((key) => {
        const scale = scales[key];
        if (scale.axis !== 'y') {
          return;
        }
        const yCoordinate = scale.getPixelForValue(ZERO_COORDINATE);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fillRect(0, yCoordinate, 200, 5);
      });
    },
```

I had first attempted to use `afterBuildTicks`, but that didn't draw the line - or at least it wasn't visible. Is there guidance regarding when to use the different lifecycle hooks? Some seem obvious, others less so.

If I use the chart's context in any lifecycle hook, how do I ensure what I draw is on top of the chart? I saw an example where someone changed the background by supplying a `beforeDraw` callback - is the stacking context managed by order in which we draw via the different hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a diagram in the chart.js [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/plugins.html#rendering) that shows when each hook is being called in the rendering process and what chart.js does between those hooks like drawing datasets, grids etc.

If you want to make sure what you are drawing is on top of everything else you will need to use the `afterDraw` hook to draw the things on the canvas that you want there.

[image]